# Dynamically show images into a Microstrategy dossier based on a metric, an attribute or a text field

Tags: image, dynamic, microstrategy, image-thresholding, dossier

I have a Microstrategy dossier and I want to show an image when the dossier is executed if an attribute has a date different than yesterday.

If this attribute has the date of yesterday, the image does not need to be shown.

How I can do this?

Thanks for your help :)

I am trying to use a threshold in a grid but I don't know if it is OK or there is another way better to do it. I am new in Micro and try to find the best way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.